# Diferencia entre tuplas y otros Objetos

Tags: c#

Cual es la diferencia entre **tuplas** y **coleciones, list o dicctionay**.

Se pueden hacer comparaciones en la **tuplas**, cual es la ventaja de usarlas.

Comment: [Mira esto](http://thatcsharpguy.com/post/correcto-colecciones/)

Comment: muy didáctico, lastima que no hable de tuplas,gracias

Comment: Estaria bueno que comentaras que sabes hasta ahora al respecto. Son dos cosas muy diferentes y se usan para cosas muy diferentes.. Si no la pregunta cae como muy amplia.

Answer (score 0):

Una diferencia entre Tuplas y colecciones que veo es que en las primeras se pueden utilizar diferentes tipos de datos  y en las colecciones[generica solo se puede especificar un tipo dato!

```
(string x , int y, bool z) = ("benjamin",30,true);
        Console.WriteLine($"{x}: {y}: {z}");

//Listas
           List<string> lista = new List<string>();
       lista.Add("uno");
       lista.Add("dos");
          foreach(string s in lista) 
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]